# SQS message pulling with server start-up code OR initialize code (Ruby Rails)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-sqs

I am process of implementing Amazon SQS service for processing lot of messages to persist it database. I am able to push the message using right_aws gem. I am also able to pull the message with example provided for gem.

I may end-up having multiple instances of ruby/rails server pulling and processing message (using lock and timeout feature of SQS). I would like to explore opportunity to pull the message using some start-up script or initialize during starting ruby/rails server and have component always running and processing messages till server is stopped.

Can someone please share some reference on how this can be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that, if the processing is not part of a online request you need to answer is by writing dedicated scripts that will have a loop always running (and maybe sleeping if there isn't much work to do).

You will pull a message, process it, delete it and continue to the next.

Run these processes at the machine startup and monitor them using something like [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/)